# Are the residuals of quasipoisson regression in logged scale?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, residuals, poisson-regression

I was interested in knowing if for a quasipoisson regression, the residuals are on a log scale

If this is my model

```
mdl<-glm(y ~ x1 +x1, family="quasipoisson")
```

To get the slope on the response scale, I do this

```
exp(mdl$coefficients[2])-1
```

If I want the residuals as well on the response scale, do I have to do the same thing?

```
exp(mdl$residuals)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. $\exp(\beta_1)-1$ is not "the slope" -- the model with the canonical link isn't linear on the scale of the response, so what would it be a "slope" of?
2. There are a variety of kinds of residuals commonly associated with a GLM (deviance, Anscombe, Pearson, working). None of them are on the log scale.

The ones you're referring to there would be the working residuals (whereas if you had done `residuals(mdl)` you'd get deviance residuals by default).

For a Poisson model, the working residuals are $\frac{y_i-\hat{\mu}_i}{\hat{\mu}_i}$.
[For a quasiPoisson model they'd presumably be scaled to adjust for the dispersion.]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the difference between different type of residuals in glm. I will have a read now.